# Specialize template with const and non-const version of another template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct A {...};
```

Which I want to specialize with another template type `B`.

However, I'd like to make this specialization work for both `B` and `const B` versions. Is it possible?

I've already tried this approach:

```
template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct A {...};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct A<T, std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, B<U>>::value || std::is_same<T, const B<U>>::value, void>::type
{
...
}
```

But it fails to compile, giving me `error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization`

Comment: is `B` a type or a template type ?

Comment: Just a thought that occurred: can you specialize for both `B` and `B const`, implement the functionality in the const version, and derive the other from that? If that works, you don't need to deal with the sfinae tmp stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a traits for `is_B` and use it:

```
template <typename T> struct is_BT : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_BT<B<T>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_BT<const B<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct A<T, std::enable_if_t<is_BT<T>::value>>
{
// ...
};
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/iKHLmc)

Comment: `is_BT<T>::value` and not `is_BT<T>{}`?

Comment: @Yakk: So it works with compiler which doesn't support yet `constexpr`

Comment: Accepting this answer. Piotr_S offered the same solution, so credit goes to him also :)

Comment: @Jarod42 There are compilers with `enable_if_t` and no (basic) `constexpr` support?  (admittedly, `enable_if_t` is really simple, but...)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct B {};

template <typename T>
struct is_b : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_b<B<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_b<const B<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct A {};

template <typename T>
struct A<T, typename std::enable_if<is_b<T>{}>::type> {};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18dde5f023005686)

Comment: For fun, `template <typename T> struct is_b<const T> : is_b<T> {}` can replace the `const B<T>` specialization.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out my suggestion from the comments. This solution does not make use of SFINAE or other TMP techniques. It's somewhat simpler than the other suggestions, so I hope I didn't misunderstand the problem.

The idea is that you just specialize twice, both for the `B<T>` and the `B<T> const` case. To avoid having to implement the class twice, you just derive the non-const version from the const-version (to preserve const-correctness).

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct B {};

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "Generic A\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct A<B<T> const>
{
    // insert specialized functionality here
    void foo() { std::cout << "B specialization\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct A<B<T>>: public A<B<T> const>
{};


int main()
{
    A<int>().foo(); // Generic A
    A<B<int>>().foo(); // B specialization
    A<B<int> const>().foo(); // B specialization
}
```

It assumes that you need the same implementation for the both specializations (non-const and const).

Comment: This is a solution, indeed. However, my design is not finished, and I have a feeling that I will need some tweaks in const or non-const version, which can be made by extra `std::enable_if` inside struct. That's why I've accepted the solution with traits. Thanks for the idea, nevertheless.

Comment: @hweom You could still do that by redefining the tweaked methods. But no harsh feelings, you made your choice ;-)